# How to check why magento store can't send email with new order

Tags: magento-1.9, email, order-email

I'm meeting the problem with my store, I'm using 1.9.3.2, the email with orders can't send such as new order, new shipment, new invoice but contact email is working, I have checked the log file and nothing appear.

Comment: maybe there is problem with your cron, have you already tried to check that ?

Comment: I'm not setup any cron job, nothing in log

Comment: maybe you can install this extension https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler to see that the cron job on your website is running or not.

Comment: check yourself or check with your developers whether cron job is set. There are different ways one is using crontab command or it can be set in the control panel.